# Angular 4 Material stepper tags are not defined

Tags: angular, class, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-stepper

I'm trying to use Angular Material stepper, gone through the documentation but when i paste the HTML Material stepper tag inside my Angular app it tells me that it's not a known element.

HTML:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" 
#stepper="matHorizontalStepper">
<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
<form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
<ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" 
formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
</mat-form-field>
<div>
<button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
</div>
</form>
</mat-step>
<mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
<form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
<ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="secondCtrl" 
required>
</mat-form-field>
<div>
<button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
<button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
</div>
</form>
</mat-step>
<mat-step>
<ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
You are now done.
<div>
<button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
<button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
</mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Component TS:

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatStepperIntl, MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material';

export class AddSchoolComponent implements OnInit {


isLinear = false;
firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
secondFormGroup: FormGroup;

constructor(
          private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
          ) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
});
this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
});
}
}
```

App TS:

```
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatStepperIntl} from '@angular/material';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';

imports: [
MatStepperModule,
NoopAnimationsModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule,],
providers: [ MatStepperModule,
MatStepperIntl,
 {provide: MatStepperIntl, useClass: MyIntl},
],
```

Tells me in app module cannot find name MyIntl.

Error message in console:

'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("formGroup]="firstFormGroup">

I need some help knowing why app module cannot identify MyIntl class and why stepper tags are not known in my HTML.

the link i followed instructions from:
[This link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xooqlqqxexm?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts)

Documentation [link](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview)

Comment: You're basically missing the `MatFormFieldModule` import.

Comment: By the way, a module is **not** a provider.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import  **`{ MatFormFieldModule }`** from '@angular/material';
**`import { MatInputModule }`** from '@angular/material'; in **`app.ts`**

Comment: did you add them under module?

Comment: i added them in the app module.ts then put them in the imports

Comment: material stepper tags is not a known element

Comment: you also need to import import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that i used Angular bootstrap with Angular material, they doesn't work with each other, this is why it never worked with me.
I hope that helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

import this all and check
import {
      MatAutocompleteModule, MatButtonModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatPaginatorModule,
      MatCardModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatChipsModule, MatDatepickerModule,
      MatDialogModule, MatDividerModule, MatGridListModule, MatIconModule, MatInputModule,
      MatListModule, MatMenuModule, MatProgressBarModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      MatRadioModule, MatSelectModule, MatSidenavModule, MatSliderModule, MatSortModule,
      MatSlideToggleModule, MatSnackBarModule, MatTableModule, MatTabsModule, MatToolbarModule,
      MatTooltipModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatExpansionModule, MatStepperModule, MatDatepicker,MatNativeDateModule
    } from '@angular/material';

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule
  ]
})
```

Comment: it's not working, do i have to import this inside the component i need to use stepper in or inside app.component.ts, i added inside app.component.ts

Comment: Uncaught Error: Invalid provider for MatStepperIntl. useClass cannot be undefined.
           Usually it happens when:
           1. There's a circular dependency (might be caused by using index.ts (barrel) files).
           2. Class was used before it was declared. Use forwardRef in this case.

This is from the console about useclass myintl

Comment: add this in Component TS

Comment: still not working, tells me on material tags that its not a known element

Answer (score 0):

Please take note that modules (such as `MatButtonModule`, `BrowserModule`, etc.) should be imported in your app's module and **not** your component(s).

Please read the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io) before getting started with Angular. You can also check out the API tab for the import statement that you need (and the module that you need in order for the Material component you want to use to work)

(P.S. I recommend that you use a feature module for Material components.)

`material.module.ts`:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatStepperModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```ts
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// etc.

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule,
    // etc.
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```